# how dose MPMoviePlayerController play an audio (video) with a url which is untrusted certificate?

Tags: ios, ssl, mpmovieplayercontroller

how dose  `MPMoviePlayerController`  play an audio (video) with a url which is **untrusted certificate**?

there is an error log like this ===>

*NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed
(kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)*

If only ask a request by using NSURLConnection/NSURLSession, I know use its delegate to accept the untrusted certificate.(like loading a image)

But if only playing a url with untrusted certificate, how to handle this part?
I have tried to add a NSURLConnection and have already run the delegate `(connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:)`
before playing an audio, and I found out the error message:

*NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed
(kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)*

is gone, but still can't playing the audio successfully.

anybody know??

Answer (score 2):

I also posted the question in Apple, and I got the answer.
MPMoviePlayerController can't play untrusted certificate.

Instead, we can use AVPlayer to play audio, video with untrusted certificate.

here is my code, works fine

```
- (IBAction)clickPlayBtn:(id)sender
{

    NSURL *sourceMovieURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https//:xxxxxxx"];

    AVURLAsset *movieAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:sourceMovieURL options:nil];
    [movieAsset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:movieAsset];
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [player play];
}

// AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate
- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader
shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)authenticationChallenge
{
    //server trust
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = authenticationChallenge.protectionSpace;
    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        [authenticationChallenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:authenticationChallenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:authenticationChallenge];
        [authenticationChallenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:authenticationChallenge];

    }
    else{ // other type: username password, client trust..
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: do you know any reason for none of the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods being called?

Answer (score 0):

For Swift it looks something like that:

```
let sourceMovieURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!

let movieAsset:AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: sourceMovieURL, options: nil)
movieAsset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: movieAsset)
let player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
let playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds; // or self.view.layer.bounds when placed in a controller
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect

self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)  // or self.view.layer...
player.play()
```

...and don't forget to add `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to your View(Controller) which look like this:

```
func resourceLoader(resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge authenticationChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) -> Bool {
    //server trust
    let protectionSpace:NSURLProtectionSpace =   authenticationChallenge.protectionSpace;
    if (protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust)
    {
        authenticationChallenge.sender!.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: authenticationChallenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!), forAuthenticationChallenge: authenticationChallenge)
        authenticationChallenge.sender!.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(authenticationChallenge)

    }
    else{ // other type: username password, client trust..
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: does this actually works with "https"? I thought AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods were never called with standard protocols like http or https

Comment: Yes this works for https. But you may need to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity when using self-signed certificates.